# When using clojure's korma sqlite3 helpers, what's the default path for the sqlite3 database?

Tags: sqlite, clojure, korma

When using korma.db, defdb can take a sqlite3 helper to establish a connexion to a sqlite3 database. However, I've tried placing the database on the root of the project directory, alongside project.clj, and on the resources directory, but when I try to use the db I get:

> Failure to execute query with SQL:
>   SELECT "examples".* FROM "examples"  ::  []
>   SQLException:
>    Message: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: examples)

Needless to say my sqlite database contains an examples table. When trying to do this, I get a sqlite.db file of zero bytes placed on the root project dir.

I'm doing this from lein repl within the project, by the way.

Edit: This is what I do when it fails:

```
(use 'korma.db)
(defdb db (sqlite3 {:db "filename.db"}))
(use 'korma.core)
(defentity examples)
(select examples)
```

Comment: Please provide the code you used to connect to the db and send the query

Comment: I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Not getting the same result. I've tried the statements you gave, and got a "filename.db" created in the root directory as I might expect. I added a "examples" table to that database, and then it worked fine. Do you still have this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anybody is wondering or runs into this...

Using version `[korma "0.4.2"]`
and `[org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc "3.7.15-M1"]`
in my `project.clj`:

My project structure looks like:

```
root/project.clj
root/db/dev.sqlite3
root/src/...
```

and this is how I use korma to access the db:

```
(use 'korma.db)
(defdb mydb {:classname "org.sqlite.JDBC"
      :subprotocol "sqlite"
      :subname "db/dev.sqlite3"})
```

Basically, using subname, I'm able to search in the root of the lein project. I added `db/` in the subname per my dir structure above.